# Getting notified when a client closes unexpectedly in JBoss Netty

Tags: netty

Is there a listener in Netty server-side, which will be notified when the client closes unexpectedly (say when the LAN cable in the client m/c is removed). None of the methods in DefaultChannelHandler is getting invoked. Assume the client is inactive (not sending/receiving any data) when the LAN cable was unplugged.

Or do we have to implement a Keep-Alive monitor in server side to check if channel is valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Practically, there is no way to detect an unexpectedly dropped connection in TCP/IP.  If there's a way to do that, it should not be called 'unexpectedly'. :-)

The most robust way to detect a dropped connection is to send a message periodically or to wait for a message with timeout, such as sending a ping message.

To implement this behavior, you can use `IdleStateHandler`.  Insert it into your pipeline and make your handler extend `IdleStateAwareChannelHandler` or `IdleStateAwareChannelUpstreamHandler`.

Alternatively, if the clients and servers run in a well controlled network such as LAN, you could configure your operating system so that it sends TCP keep-alive packet more frequently.  For more information, refer to [TCP keepalive HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/usingkeepalive.html).  However, I doubt this will work reliably under WAN environment.  (If someone experimented with TCP keepalive timeout in a WAN environment, please share your story.)

Comment: Thanks Trustin. Will try the mentioned behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a `ReadTimeoutHandler` to your pipeline? I believe this would throw a `ReadTimeoutException` after the server had not read data from the channel for the given number of seconds.

I've only used this on clients to implement reconnect (like the UpTime example), but it may also work here.

Comment: I used IdleStateHandler in server with periodic ping mechanism from Client. That worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Designed and implemented fail-closed keep-alives. Important thing here is to close the channel after a timeout, and reopen it.